# CCSprite Rotation Speed is very fast using UIRotationGestureRecognizer Cocos2D-iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am using the following code to rotate a sprite but the rotation speed is very fast and not sync with the rotation of fingers.

In the init method I have written the following code

```
UIRotationGestureRecognizer* rot = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action: @selector (rotateSelector:)];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:rot];
```

The selector implementation is written below.

```
- (void)rotateSelector: (UIRotationGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer
    {
        rotation = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES([gestureRecognizer rotation]);
        mySprite.rotation += rotation;

    }
```

I think the problem is in the following line
mySprite.rotation += rotation;

But I can't figure it out, how to sync the rotation of CCSprite with rotation of fingers.

Comment: assign rotation, don't add it

Comment: if i dont add it then next time when i rotate the sprite then it starts from its original position... in that case speed is slow but not starts from last rotating angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than add the gesture rotation to the sprite's rotation property, which you don't want, adding the rotation difference will give you the results you want. Like:

```
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
    self.lastRotAngle = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES([recognizer rotation]);
}
else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
    float rotation = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES([recognizer rotation]);

    sprite.rotation += rotation - self.lastRotAngle;
    self.lastRotAngle = rotation;
}
```

I hope this helped.